# MVC View Directory Location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I started with MVC project.
and got stuck up with this thing.

Is it possible to have `mvc` View directly Inside `Views` Folder.

Why does it always search inside
    `Views/Home/Home.cshtml` or
    `Views/Shared/Home.cshtml`

My view name is `Home.cshtml`

Cant i have it directly as Views/Home.cshtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it always search inside `Views/Home/Home.cshtml`

The default web view engine is setup to look for views based on the controller they are being rendered from i.e. `Views/{Controller}/View.cshtml` and then subsequently  `Views/Shared/View.cshtml` for views which are shared across multiple controllers.

> Can't I have it directly as Views/Home.cshtml

Yes you can, all you need to do is give the full path to where your view is e.g

```
View("~/Views/Home.cshtml")
```

However, I don't really see why you would want to. MVC keeps your views tidy & makes it easy to see which views are rendered by which controllers.

Comment: where to specify full path? in global.asax routing? can you elaborate?

Comment: @MandarJogalekar when you are returning the view from your controller action.